# Laravel: not allow multiple user to update the same database record

Tags: laravel, vue.js, eloquent

In Laravel is there any way to lock particular record with the user and don't allow another user to edit the same record.

For example, User A edit a record R1. This record will lock for the other Users. At the same time, if any other user tries to edit the record R1 then it show the error message at front-end that 'User A is currently editing this record.' and not allow to update the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default MySQL locks the database when one query updates a record and other queries are made in queue to wait for the current query to finish first.

So basically two users cannot update the same record at the same time. It's not possible.

However if you mean like when a user starts editing a form or something, in that very moment you want to lock all fields of the form in the database so that when other users cannot even access the form until the first user stops editing it then you can go with Stony's answer. Just have a field in the table which gets populated with the id of the user currently editing the form, that way you have a way to check if:

- some user is editing the form by checking the field if its null or not
- also to fetch the user based upon id and show the message who is editing the form

I advise you to make field nullable and foreign key so that you can use an eloquent relationship to fetch the user easily.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't mean a Transaction where the table is locked in that moment where the user save something that you don't have inconsistency.

I think in your case you have to make a field in your database `in_use`. When a user open the edit form you write the user id in that field and lock the form. When the next user enter the form you write a message that user XY is editing the record at the moment. But then you have to look that you unlock the record if the user leave the form / record.

Perhaps something like this could help:

https://packagist.org/packages/tokenly/laravel-record-lock